# Does adding your frequent flier number to a person's reservation grant them any of your privileges?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs

I know that if I enter my own frequent flier number on another person's reservation/check-in, I will get miles for their flight. But let's say I have a certain status with the airline - would entering the frequent flier number grant the same privileges to the other passenger? Or perhaps get them higher on the upgrade list in case of an overbooking?

Comment: On all the airlines I've used, you won't get miles for the flight. I was denied miles when Katherine (me) flew with Kate (also me)'s ff number

Comment: @KateGregory oh, then my assumption is mistaken

Comment: I doubt this is possible - I very much assume most (all?) airline systems will match names.  What is possible at least with some airlines, however, is to have to different frequent flier numbers for crediting miles and for benefits.  (At least United has - or had? - two different fields for that in their system.)

Comment: Of course, it shouldn't be too hard to check: Just enter your FF number at online checkin and see if the system even accepts it.

Comment: @npl Just because the system accepts the number does not mean it will be applied to the record, nor any benefits associated with it. The number *and name* must match exactly.  I have had trouble before because "Mr" got added to my first name in the reservation, for example. The FQTV/FQTS distinction would not be relevant.

Comment: @choster Sure, but it would be a first test.  If the system rejects it already at that stage, well ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the frequent flier number is only valid for that single passenger.  On a multi-passenger itinerary, if the principal booking passenger has status with an airline, some privileges might extend to other passengers on the same booking (e.g. United will give an earlier boarding category to such passengers), but you'll only earn miles or points for yourself.  Otherwise, status passengers could abuse their privilege and let almost anyone avail themselves of the status.

The only way to get other passengers benefits from a frequent flier number would be for them to have their own number (aside from the boarding priority you can pass along to traveling companions).  Of course, in this case, they'll just be earning points for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

There are some borderline cases. When you book a ticket with miles for someone else, and you're on a higher tier, the traveler might be treated a little better. I booked once a ticket on Air France for someone, which had a few segments. I was a Platinum member back then, and the person traveling on this ticket faced delays on one of the segments, potentially jeopardizing the rest of the flights, and AF staff went really out of their way to help. They mentioned that my status was partly the reason.

But on the other hand, I haven't seen yet airlines extend other benefits (lounge access, upgrades, etc) to people flying on tickets procured by higher-tier members.